# Html to Formatted Text C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a column on my table (SQL Server 2014).
Which contains, like `<p><strong>Content</strong></p>`

I want to display it on my Table View, currently I'm using MVC 5.
Normally, I just need to add `<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Content)</td>`

It shows as is. I want to display it with formatted Html base on the content of my data.
Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Content)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just give up too early. I got the answer.

`@Html.Raw(item.Content)`

Thank you.